# Conversion of Epoch Date to Human Readable format in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am having an Epoch date which is coming from Web Services, I want to display it in Human Readable format as, July 12, 2012, but my code always shows 16/01/1970 for any Epoch Date. I don't know where I am Wrong or How to convert Epoch Date to Date in Java. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**Code:**

```
Date.setText(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(newsDetail.getDate_Posted()))));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that `Long.parseLong(newsDetail.getDate_Posted())` is returning seconds from epoch not *milliseconds*.

If you always see 16/01/1970, then `Long.parseLong(newsDetail.getDate_Posted())` is between 1296000000 and 1382400000. It turns out that if I multiple these minimum and maximum number by 1000, I see dates between **26/1/2011** and **21/10/2013**. I'm guessing that the date you are expecting falls in this new range.

Try using:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
date.setText(sdf.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(newsDetail.getDate_Posted()) * 1000)));
```